# Ler documento array de bytes word no browser

Tags: c#

Tenho uma rotina de `upload` e `download` em um site que está funcionando. Contudo, não consigo fazer visualizar arquivos tipo word, diretamente no browser, desejo visualizar como pdf. O que eu estou fazendo é salva o documento no disco e enviar o array de bytes para  itextsharp.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\arquivo.doc", FileMode.Create);
//Escrevo arquivo no fluxo
stream.Write(doc.Arquivo, 0, doc.Arquivo.Length);
//Fecho fluxo pra finalmente salvar em disco
stream.Close();

new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-word");
```

Comment: Sua aplicação é ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Sim,asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Sem usar componentes externos (como o [Aspose.Words](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/), que é pago), pode ser feito da seguinte forma, usando objetos de interoperabilidade do Word:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass MSdoc;
object Unknown = Type.Missing;

private void word2PDF(object Source, object Target)
{   
    if (MSdoc == null)MSdoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

    try
    {
        MSdoc.Visible = false;
        MSdoc.Documents.Open(ref Source, ref Unknown,
             ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
             ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
             ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
             ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
         MSdoc.Application.Visible = false;
          MSdoc.WindowState =   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

        object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

        MSdoc.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref Target, ref format,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
               ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
      }
       catch (Exception e)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
       }
     finally
      {
        if (MSdoc != null)
        {
            MSdoc.Documents.Close(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
            //WordDoc.Application.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
        }

        WordDoc.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
    }
}
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889922/1314276).

O problema é que isso exige o Word instalado no servidor, o que não é uma boa para aplicações ASP.NET MVC.

> Pretendo melhorar esta resposta assim que eu conseguir uma boa alternativa sem custos que faça essa conversão.

Comment: Verdade  instalar o word é um problema, tentei encontrar uma outra solução e até agora nada.

Comment: puts, até agora não encontrei alguma solução open source, para esse problema. Alguém tem?

Answer (score 0):

Para funcionar a visualização do documento no seu navegador é mediante a plugin, igual acontece com o seu PDF.

Existe um para **google chrome** [`Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) .

Comment: Não tem outra forma de visualizar sem se por plugin? Estou tentando conversar para pdf e não funciona.